# What are these search results?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I did a query for ["D&D Insider"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=D%26D+Insider) yesterday and two weird results were included:

[image: search results for "D&D Insider"]

They are present for any query including "D&D" (which gets passed to the query as "dd"). They look to me like old tag descriptions for the original [dd] tag.

I couldn't flag them as "noise" (since I couldn't click on them and they are not actual Q or A that are held by Community) so I'm posting them here to see if anyone knows about how to remove them.

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be seeing that.  I can't fix it either, so I posted it [here on meta.so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66521/orphaned-tag-wikis-showing-up-in-question-search-results).

Comment: @CRoss: Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tag wikis could be returned by search; this will be fixed in the next deploy.